# Execute cycle only for CASE WHEN specific condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

If write this

```
    DECLARE res INTEGER;
    DECLARE loop_res INTEGER;


    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 INTO loop_res;



        FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
            SELECT loop_res + i INTO loop_res;
        END LOOP;


        SELECT 
        case
            WHEN some_variable < 3   
                THEN  --some result
            WHEN some_variable  >= 3
                THEN  loop_res
        END
        INTO res;
```

This works, but here anyway will execute LOOP statement right?

There is possible to execute LOOP statement only in case, if `WHEN some_variable   >= 3` ?

I am trying :

```
        SELECT 
        case
            WHEN some_variable  < 3   
                THEN   --some result
            WHEN some_variable   >= 3
                THEN  
                    FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
                        SELECT loop_res + i INTO loop_res;
                    END LOOP;
                    loop_res
        END
        INTO res;
```

gives error `syntax error at or near "FOR" at character ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to mix PL/PgSQL and SQL. They're not really the same thing.

`SELECT ... CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END ...`, like you've written is regular SQL. It can't embed PL/PgSQL statements.

PL/PgSQL `CASE` doesn't appear in a regular `SELECT`, just by its self as a control structure. It doesn't support `INTO` since it isn't a `SELECT`. It's of the form `CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END CASE;`

See [PL/PgSQL control structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

You could write:

```
CASE
    WHEN some_variable < 3 THEN 
        res := 0;
    WHEN some_variable >= 3 THEN  
        FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
            loop_res := loop_res + i;
        END LOOP;
        res := loop_res;
END CASE;
```

which is a PL/PgSQL `CASE`. The whole approach looks bizarre, but you're only showing dummy code so I can't really say what you're really trying to do. It's pretty unusual that you need to `LOOP` rather than just using some smarter SQL, but it does happen.

In this case it strikes me as likely that you'd turn out to be able to write a query using `union`s, `with` queries (CTEs), and/or `generate_series` to avoid the need for slow PL/PgSQL looping and control structures.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am not do really  something, I am just learn and test how to use cycle statement in concret CASE condition.

Comment: @OTARIKI Ah, that makes more sense. Whenever you can avoid using `LOOP` in PL/PgSQL you should. It's very inefficient compared to doing the same work in ordinary SQL.